# Crawling the Link Webpart in 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am hoping that someone here can help me with an issue I am having searching the Quick Links webpart within a page. Many of my users have prefer Google Docs to storing documents in SharePoint. They directly link to these external Google Docs with the Quick Link webpart on a page. I hope to change this with governance and future trainings but in the meantime is it possible to use a KQL or managed property to search these links title?
I understand that the content of the Google Doc isn't searchable but I would love to find a way to use a highlighted content webpart to show all of the docs.google.* links in one location.

Just for background information I am a Hub owner but I do not have access to the Admin Panel. I have switched on "always index all Web Parts on this site".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid that is not possible for the time being.

The links added in Quick Links web part are not identified as items (or links to be specific) but **page contents**. They do not have a corresponding crawled/managed property (to be used in the Highlighted Content web part).
As a result, when search for the links in Quick Links web part by using link title, for example, it returns the site page instead.

See a related UserVoice post here: [Quick Link - Link titles are searchable and appear in search results by default.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36375154-quick-link-link-titles-are-searchable-and-appear)
Vote for it if you have the same request.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. Thank you so much for answering my question. I voted for that post you shared.